# Вычисление суммы ряда

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

мне нужно сделать код так, чтобы получился пример под цифрой 2
но код я смог сделать только так, что у меня получается пример под цифрой 1
Как мне это переделать?
1. 1+1/2^2!+ 1/3^2!+ 1/4^2!+ 1/5^2!+... до Вводимого числа E
 2. 0,001^2+0,002^2/2!+ 0,003^2/3!+...до Вводимого числа E

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


int main()

{
   using namespace std;

   float e, s, i = 1, f = 1, prev;

   cout << "value for e =";
   cin >> e;

   s = 0;
   do
   {
       s = s + pow((1 / f), 2);
       i++;
       prev = 1 / f;
       f *= i;
       cout << "s="<< s<< endl;
   } while (1 / f >= e);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Давайте сначала и медленно :) Что вы хотите получить? Что за "вводимое число Е", где оно участвует? Не у вас в коде, в задании. Я догадываюсь, что это :), но поверьте, когда вы сможете изложить задание ясно и четко - прояснится и то, как его делать. Напишите ряд, который надо посчитать, нормально (он не зависит ни от какого параметра? Точно?)

Comment: могу дописать, то,что вводимое число E это то число, до которого будет идти последовательность 0,001^2+0,002^2/2!+ 0,003^2/3!+...

Comment: Опять не то... Понимаете, вы сами для себя не сформулировали задачу...

Comment: я не настолько красноречивый, уж простите)

Comment: ну или например, если мы введем число E 5, то последовательность будет идти 0,001^2+0,002^2/2!+ 0,003^2/3!+0,004^2/4!+0,005^2/5!

Comment: @Андрей пожалуйста, перепишите вопрос, что бы было понятнее) Для переноса текста на новую строку необходимо оставить одну пустую строку между двумя другими

Answer (score 4):

Вот как лучше сформулировать задание:

Нужно вычислить сумму ряда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для `x=0.001`, останавливая вычисления, когда очередной член становится меньше вводимого значения `eps`.

Тогда все просто - лучше только не "в лоб", а заметить, что отношение соседних членов равно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда очень просто получается нужный код:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x = 0.001;
    double eps;

    cin >> eps;

    double term = 1, sum = 1;
    for(int n = 2;term > eps; ++n)
        sum += (term *= double(n)/(n-1)/(n-1));
    sum *= x*x;

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Второй вариант - вычисление суммы для `N` членов - столь же простое:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x = 0.001;
    int N;

    cin >> N;

    double term = 1, sum = 1;
    for(int n = 2; n <= N; ++n)
        sum += (term *= double(n)/(n-1)/(n-1));
    sum *= x*x;

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

P.S. Правда, есть одна хитрость - чисто с точки зрения машинной точности такие суммы лучше считать от малых членов к большим, но для данного задания это уже перебор :)

А вообще, в пределе эта сумма равна [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно здесь (?). Тут - же вы написали прогрессию гармонического ряда для степени 2, что разве неясно чему она равна. Ну или = Пи в квадрате / на 6. А в Результат также можно добавить будет 0. Всё. Компьютерных алгоритмов не знаю и не знаю: как писать шифры.